# Could there be a separate lists.se area

Tags: discussion, migration, list-questions

I understand both sides of the "Lists questions" debate. Personally I find them very informative and end up on those threads often through google. But I also understand the desire to keep all the se sites "pure" with respects to the area.

So why couldn't there be a lists.se site that caters to these kinds of questions? The tags could designate the type of list it is for. Then all those nasty horrible list questions that the mods hate, but many find so useful, could be migrated to a single site.

Comment: as far as I understand something like that has been tested already - long time ago, with _Programmers.SE_. Didn't work particularly well... rather the opposite

Answer (score 12):

That would amount to a site where everything was on-topic, like say, Yahoo! Answers.  I think that would just be contributing a lot more noise and very little signal to the Internet.

Comment: I disagree. The users would control the valid questions. Anyway nobody seems to be able to decide how harness the usefulness of some of the list questions. Why? What is preventing this?

Comment: @ElGringoGrande Users on sites with focused topics don't even control valid questions.  List questions grow out of control and, with very few notable exceptions, no one maintains them.