# Feature Request: "Ask For List"

Tags: feature-request, list-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could there be a separate lists.se area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127322/could-there-be-a-separate-lists-se-area)

A number of times users ask open questions like...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books
- [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
- [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

...that have multiple "good" answers, and have no one "right" answer.

For example questions that start with:

> What is the best FOO?
>   What are some good FOOs?
>   What are the FOO elements of the set BAR?
>   etc

These questions are against the current policy and as such are considered off-topic.

We propose to change the policy and allow them in a separate area as follows:

A new button, **`Ask For List`**, will be added next to or below **`Ask Question`**.

The functionality of a `List` would be the same as that of a `Question` except there is no green tick and no one right answer.  `List`s are designed to be left open.  People add new **items** (not answers) to the List and upvote/downvote existing items.  Answers are displayed in descending order of votes by default.

`Lists` have a separate tab from `Questions`, by placing a `Lists` tab between `Questions` and `Tags`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. It is a question & answer site. This kind of questions belong in a discussion forum.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: It's not a duplicate.  This proposes new Lists tab, whereas the other proposal is vague but seems to be suggesting a separate site.

Comment: @Chrichiray: I think `Lists` and free-for-all discussions are not the same thing.  I have found many of the closed List questions very useful, as have many.  It is a shame they are going to waste.

Comment: @user1131467 - If you've found the list questions useful then how can you say they've gone to waste? They are closed... not deleted (_yet!_)

Comment: @M.Babcock: No, I mean that there are more such useful Lists that would exists if they were allowed and supported with a feature request like the above.

Comment: @user1131467 - The lists do exist, it's called Google.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Everyone agrees that crowd-sourced lists are of better quality than the results you get from Google.  Compare those closed SO Lists, to an equivilant web search.

Comment: @user1131467 - The biggest problem I have with list questions is they require maintenance in order to stay relevant and they generally produce link only answers which is not ideal for SE. We like rich answers and questions that don't require constant attention.

Comment: Please roll back your last two edits and just close the question.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Doesn't work, it says "has answers" so cant be deleted.

Comment: I didn't say delete, I said close. If you can't do it then flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @M.Babcock: No close button. I had already flagged it.

Comment: @user1131467 on a slightly related note, I realise question lists aren't encouraged on SE, but have you seen the tag wikis? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info for example. These places are great places to put resources, links etc for a specific community and are thoroughly underused, in my opinion. You'll get rep for excellent edits to tag wikis; it's not much (+2 per edit) but hey. Sorry you had a bit of a rough ride with meta - don't take it too hard, we've all had feature requests that seemed good at the time downvoted :)

Comment: I too think that it'd be nice to have some specific place to aim people asking for "shopping recommendations" -- but I just don't think any place that really allows _votes_ is going to cut it. Ancient items are more likely to have a giant pile of up votes, displacing newer items that might be nicer. Or, the Neat New Thing might get a giant pile of enthusiasm votes, but not be as good as the decade-old Known But Boring. Vote decay might help, but it doesn't seem right either. SE is very good at what it does, and diluting that might wreck the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, "list" questions are off-topic here. This is a Q&A site for specific, answerable questions.

We won't be adding a feature to the user interface that promotes, encourages, or otherwise engages questions that are completely off-topic.

Moreover, note that **none** of those questions that you listed are "open". In fact, not only have they been closed, they have been locked and had the following notice applied to them:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @user: The policy is not going to be changed. Those questions don't work on a Q&A site.

Comment: Meta Stackexchange is the appropriate place to propose new features and policy changes correct?

Comment: @user: Yes, Meta is the place you'd propose new features. But you're not going to get very far by proposing stuff that is completely antithetical to the goal here.

Comment: You are free to suggest that my feature request isn't a good idea, but it is inappropriate to say that it is "off-topic" and "against policy".  Every feature that doesn't exist yet is off-topic and against policy! :)

Comment: You misunderstand, @user. The Establishment isn't saying that *this Meta post* is off-topic. He's saying that the feature you're requesting would enable posts on SO that are far afield from those it handles well. Whether list questions are acceptable on SE sites is a well-worn area of discussion. Your feature request doesn't change things enough to render those discussions moot.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Please provide links to those well-worn discussions.

Comment: @user: Start [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list), then poke around.